# Translation of "want to be taught by him"?

Tags: passive-voice

I know *to teach* is 教え, but I'm not sure how to use the passive form. Google Translate gave 彼が教えしたいです, but that seems *he wants to teach (sb)*. How about 教わたい?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

教え is a noun meaning *teaching*. What you want is verb  教わる : おそわる (to be taught). 
 
 *Note that there is another similar verb which is 教える : おしえる (to teach). 
 
 Although it's grammatically correct to turn 教える into it's passive form 教えられる, it's more common and preferred to use the 教わる instead*

> **simple:**
> **彼に[教]{おそ}わりたいです**
>   *I want to be taught by him.*
>
> **In this case we can use 教えて since by adding もらう, it modified the verb into (receive action[verb] from someone) :**
>  **彼に[教]{おし}えてもらいたいです** 
>   *I want (to receive a favor of being taught) by him*

Comment: I'm newbie so i don't really know why the answer get accepted but get voted down. I'm okay with downvote but please enlightenment me of my mistakes.thanks.

Comment: I have accepted your answer and someone else has downvoted. I would like to why too.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but I think they would rather you had said, 彼に教えてもらいたい or 彼に教えていただきたい.

Comment: As @Earthling mentioned in the comment above, we have the passive verb [教]{おそ}わる (to be taught). And its たい form is 教わりたい.

Comment: @chocolate ah i see, in case that a passive standalone verb is available such as 教わる、does 教えられる cannot be used at all or is it just not preferred (not common) ?

Comment: I think 教わりたい is more common and preferred at least in normal situations, though I don't think 教えられたい would be grammatically incorrect.

Comment: @chocolate Thanks, i have improved the answer. I thought 教わる mentioned was おしわる and was a typo since i cannot find it in dictionary :)

Comment: @ Alice28 教わる is commonly read おそわる and we rarely say おしわる but some persons say おしわる as their dialect. I first know them.